# Ansible: playbook calling Role in a directory that is in the roles directory

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I would like to shape my directory structure of my ansible roles and playbooks.

Currently I have a directory structure like.

```
group_vars
    * all 
    * group-one
        - group-vars.yml
        - group-vault.yml
    ...
host_vars
  - server1.yml
plays
    - java_plays
       * deploy_fun_java_stuff.yml
    * deploy_playbook.yml
roles
    - role1 
            - tasks
               * main.yml
            - handlers 
            - (the rest of the needed directories)
    - role2
    - java 
        - java_role1
            - tasks
               * main.yml
            - handlers 
            - (the rest of the needed directories)
```

I would like to be able to call upon the role `java_role1` in the play `deploy_fun_java_stuff.yml`

I can call

```
 ---
 - name: deploy fun java stuff
   hosts: java
   roles:
    - { role: role1 }
```

but I cannot call (I've tried multiple ways).  Is this possible?

> ---
>
> ```
>  - name: deploy fun java stuff
>    hosts: java
>    roles:
>     - { role: java/java_role1 }
> ```

What I really want to accomplish is to be able to structure my plays in an orderly fashion along with my roles. 
I will end up with a large number of both roles and plays I would like to organize them.

I can handle this with a separate ansible.cfg file for each play directory but I cannot add those cfg files to ansible tower (So I'm looking for an alternate solution).

Comment: What's wrong with `java/java_role1`?

Comment: Role not found error. 

to note, it is looking for the role in the working directory which is `.../plays/java_plays/`

Comment: java_role1 is not in roles directory its in /java/. Moving to roles would work but i guess you want in this hierarchy right ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need to set the relative path properly. Ansible first applies the given path relative to the called playbooks directory, then looks in the current working path (from which you are executing the `ansible-playbook` command) and finally checks in `/etc/ansible/roles`, so instead of `{ role: java/java_role1 }` in your dir structure you could use `{ role: ../../roles/java/java_role1 }` or `{ role: roles/java/java_role1 }`. Yet another option would be to configure the paths in which ansible is looking for roles. For that you could set the `roles_path` inside your projects `ansible.cfg` as described in the [Ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html).

Based on your example:

**Dir tree:**

```
ansible/
├── hosts
│   └── dev
├── plays
│   └── java_plays
│       └── java.yml
└── roles
    ├── java
    │   └── java_role1
    │       └── tasks
    │           └── main.yml
    └── role1
        └── tasks
            └── main.yml
```

To test it, the play would include `java_role1` and `role1`.

**plays/java_plays/java.yml:**

```
---
 - name: deploy java stuff
   hosts: java
   roles:
    - { role: roles/role1 }
    - { role: roles/java/java_role1 }
```

For testing purposes these roles simply print a debug msg.

**role1/tasks/main.yml:**

```
---
- debug: msg="Inside role1"
```

The `dev` hosts file simply sets localhost to the `java` group. Now I can use the playbook:

```
fishi@zeus:~/workspace/ansible$ ansible-playbook -i hosts/dev plays/java_plays/java.yml

PLAY [deploy java stuff] *******************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [role1 : debug] ***********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Inside role1"
}

TASK [java_role1 : debug] *************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Inside java_role1"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Now doing the same when you use `{ role: ../../roles/java/java_role1 }` and `{ role: ../../roles/role1 }` your log output inside the `TASK` brackets would show the whole relative path instead of just the role name:

```
fishi@zeus:~/workspace/ansible$ ansible-playbook -i hosts/dev plays/java_plays/java.yml

PLAY [deploy java stuff] *******************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [../../roles/role1 : debug] ***********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Inside role1"
}

TASK [../../roles/java/java_role1 : debug] *************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Inside java_role1"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: I'd like to add a comment that if you place an alternate relative roles_path in ansible.cfg, Ansible Tower will happily ignore this and then state the role could not be found upon execution. I've also had trouble getting playbooks to run that refer to roles in ../../ style paths. Tower just does something funky that's apparently not compatible with these styles of referring to where the role really is...

Answer (score 10):

Another option and one that I use is to create an ansible.cfg file in your playbook directory and place the following in it:

```
[defaults]

roles_path = /etc/ansible/roles: <custom path 1>: <custom path 2>
```

or in your case:

```
[defaults]

roles_path = /etc/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles/java
```

Then don't use any relative paths.

Comment: This is an old answer but I want to add that you can have several paths in the cfg, and they will then be treated "as same root". Very useful when for example having several customer repos with specific code/roles and some common roles!

ansible.cfg: roles_path = roles:../../shared-repo/roles
Have all roles in subdirectories like "specific" and "shared" in the roles dirs above
Then in playbook use like:
roles:
- specific/a_role
- shared/do common_stuff

and so on

Answer (score 7):

A more elegant solution (imo) is symlinking your roles directory to inside the playbooks directory.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
inventory/
playbooks/
  |-> roles -> ../roles
  |-> group_vars -> ../group_vars
  |-> host_vars -> ../host_vars
roles/
group_vars/
host_vars/
```

In my case, I created the symlink by running `ln -s ../roles playbooks/roles`